# providing multichannel service in iptv service

Tags: linux, broadcastreceiver, dvb, iptv

I'm supposed to be working on an IPTV system, now I have to figure out how providers can broadcast more than one channel from satellite at the same time
is it managed by hardware like special receivers, or software!!
if there is a study or paper about this subject I'll be much obliged to you
thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it is worth noting that some of the terms used can mean different things so to set the scene:

- IPTV - typically multicast video streams over operator owned IP networks
- OTT - 'Over the Top' Unicast video streams over public IP networks
- DVB or Broadcast - traditional broadcast TV, usually over Satalite, Cable or Terrestrial

Broadcast DCVB networks do indeed have equipment to multiplex multiple channel together at the headend and on the receivers, typically STB's in customer networks.

Looking at IPTV, a common deployment scenario is:

- Channels received at headend from Satalite, fiber links etc
- Channels sent as multicast IPTV streams over IPTV network
- Multicast receiver receives channel and feeds channel to STB to be played on TV (for example)

The key difference between unicast and multicast is that for multicast a single stream per channel is delivered across the network and at the edge the individual end users 'join' the multicast to view that channel. For unicast an individual stream is sent from the head end to the viewer for each individual viewer.

At face value it would seem that multicast is much more efficient than Unicast, but the picture is made less clear by the extra complexity of Multicast and by the fact that many viewers now watch either catch up or library content, rather than live streams. The debate can become quite emotive but I think the truth is that each solution has its place depending on the requirements for a particular deployment.

Comment: One thing to add - there is a nice diagrammatic overview here (link valid at time of whirring...): https://koovik.com/en/2018/09/21/iptv-broadcast-multicast-unicast-streaming/

Answer (score 0):

IPTV, a technology of streaming programs, he mainly through the operator-owned IP network.

IPTV generally has 1000+ channels, but the general IPTV is to charge, but different IPTV charging prices lead to the uneven quality of the market.

The best thing you can do is ask for a probationary period (from a few hours to a few days, depending on where you ask), and then see if the channel lineup, movies, and series fit your needs. As soon as you find your favorite provider, then the subscription service is divided into 1/3/6/12 months (for example, I am using GTV IPTV). so you won't be tied for a longer period of time and risk future service falling with your money.

Comment: Can you please fix the first sentence in your answer? I don't know what it means because it is ungrammatical and and can't see an obvious fix.